# Kafka deserilzation failing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have the following beans for KafkaConfig for my 2 consumers

```
   @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SyncMessage> kafkaConsumerFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 20000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 43200000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "grp_id");

        props.put(JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.model.SyncMessage");

        ErrorHandlingDeserializer<yncMessage> deserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(
                new JsonDeserializer<>(SyncMessage.class));
        deserializer.setFailedDeserializationFunction(info -> {
            log.error("Unable to deserialize message: {}", new String(info.getData()));
            return SyncMessage.DESERIALIZED_ERROR_KAFKA_MESSAGE;
        });
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SyncMessage> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SyncMessage> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
        factory.setMissingTopicsFatal(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory2() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "grp_id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory2() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory2());
        factory.setMissingTopicsFatal(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

The two consumers listen on 2 different topics. Consumer with value of type SyncMessage implements `AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, SyncMessage>, ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartedEvent>`

The other consumer who expects a value/message of type String is simpler and is as follows

```
@Service
public class MessageListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageListener.class);
    @KafkaListener(topics = "historical-publish", groupId = "grp_id")
    public void listenToMsg(String message) {
        LOGGER.error("msg is {}",message);
    }
}
```

But everytime I send a String for my consumer to get triggered it get stack trace showing both consumer's corresponding deserializations occurred and both failed.

```
:
Method [public void com.<package>.MessageListener.listenToMsg(java.lang.String)]
Bean [com.<package>.MessageListener@48ccbb32]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2942) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2887) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2854) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$57(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2772) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$4(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.8.jar:1.11.8]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.8.jar:1.11.8]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.8.jar:1.11.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2770) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2622) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2508) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2150) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1505) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1469) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Restored Stack Trace
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.checkAckArg(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:402) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:380) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2873) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:380) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2873) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.<package>.SyncMessage] to [java.lang.String] for GenericMessage [payload=SyncMessage(id=null, agentType=null, startTime=null, endTime=null, lastSyncStatus=null), headers={springDeserializerExceptionValue=[B@5721bf77, kafka_offset=31, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3f6d6943, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=historical-publish, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1707972494074, kafka_groupId=dsp_sync}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java:151) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.16.jar:6.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.java:46) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:118) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.16.jar:6.0.16]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.16.jar:6.0.16]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.16.jar:6.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:375) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.13.jar:3.0.13]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```